# Testing Spring Data Rest

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I want to test a Spring boot 2 respository as rest controller app. 
App is working well from browser ( http://localhost:8080/api/v1/ehdata ), but I cannot find an example how can I test it with Spring test environment. Very important, there are no RestControllers and Services, only Repositories annotated like this:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path = EhDataRepository.BASE_PATH, 
                        collectionResourceRel = EhDataRepository.BASE_PATH)
public interface EhDataRepository extends 
PagingAndSortingRepository<EhData, Long> {

    public static final String BASE_PATH="ehdata";
}
```

I tried with this test, but responses was empty, and status code was 404:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@WebMvcTest(EhDataRepository.class)
public class RestTest extends AbstractRestTest {
    @Autowired MockMvc mvc;

    @Test
    public void testData() throws Exception {
         mvc.perform(get("/api/v1/ehdata")
            .accept(MediaTypes.HAL_JSON_VALUE))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(header().string(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, 
                     MediaTypes.HAL_JSON_VALUE+";charset=UTF-8")
            .andReturn();
    }

}
```

thx,
Zamek

Answer (score 0):

You will need to mock the output from the respository like this based on the method you are trying to test:

```
 @MockBean
 private ProductRepo repo;
```

And then

```
Mockito.when(this.repo.findById("PR-123")
    .get())
    .thenReturn(this.product);
this.mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/products/{id}", "PR-123")
    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
    .andReturn();
```

Also, remove the server-context-path while calling API in perform() method.